# Erase and re-install

Tags: system-installation

I have switched fully to Ubuntu. I have added to many additional items and would simply like to perform an erase and reinstall. However, I can only find install packages that boot from windows or mac. Is there none for installing ubuntu from ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) Boot from an Ubuntu live DVD or an Ubuntu live USB and then install Ubuntu replacing the old OS with the new OS, the same way as installing Ubuntu on a computer that has Windows.

Comment: You can simply uninstall what you installed and should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you download the live CD installer and burn it to CD or install it to USB, it will allow you to boot the system and install Ubuntu regardless of the operating system initially installed thereupon.  There does not need to be any OS at all installed, in fact.

Download the live CD .iso here http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Comment: I must be missing something then. I have followed those instructions, and indeed the first time it worked flawlessly. Recent attempts though, have me booting to the blinking cursor only when using my flash drive.

Comment: If you created the flash drive using unetbootin, I have had problems with that.  Try the universal USB installer instead http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
Probably too obvious but make sure the BIOS is set to boot off USB

Comment: Thank you for sticking with this. Pendrivelinux seems to run through wine which does not allow for my usb to be recognized for installation.